# Magento 2.2.1 Error(Item (Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule) with the same ID "33" already exists)

Tags: error, sales, exception, magento-2.2.1

I got an error in log like

> main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule) with the same ID
>   "33" already exists. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Item
>   (Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule) with the same ID \"33\" already
>   exists. at vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php:404)"} []

How can I resolve this? Any quick solution

Comment: Are you running Magento Enterprise?

Answer (score 5):

This issue occurs if you have duplicate rows in "salesrule" database table with the same "created_in" and "update_in" range.

> > select * from salesrule where rule_id = 71;

*You should use 33 instead of 71*

The result should look like (note: row_id 198 and 388 has the same date range):

[image]

To fix, you will need to split the values in updated_in for row_id 198 and the created_id for row_id 388

```
update salesrule set updated_in = 2147480000 where row_id = 198;
update salesrule set created_in = 2147480000 where row_id = 388;
```

[image]

Comment: This works with me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please see Renon's answer above.

To further elaborate on the issue, you can search your database for other affected rules. First, get the current staging version for your site:

```
SELECT * FROM `flag` WHERE `flag_code` = 'staging';
```

You will see something like this:

```
{"current_version":"1595433660"}
```

Next, take that timestamp, and inject it into this query:

```
SELECT rule_id, GROUP_CONCAT(`row_id`)
FROM`salesrule`
WHERE(created_in <= '1595433660')
AND (updated_in > '1595433660')
GROUP BY `rule_id` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This will return the `rule_id` and `row_id` of affected Sales Rules. Update those rows using Renon's method so that only one row for each rule matches the above date conditions, and you should no longer have this problem.

**Note:** I observed this issue on Magento 2.3.5-p1